# How to rig a briefcase that has a hinge, and rotates dynamically as the handle moves?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigid-body-simulation

So I modeled a briefcase prop for my character to hold in a practice animation. I would like the character to hold it by the handle and as he moves it around, the briefcase will swing on the hinge like it would in real life, so I wouldn't have to animated it swinging. I tried using the rigid body constraint and setting it to hinge on an empty, but the suitcase starts swinging  after the handle comes to a stop, instead of swinging both at the end and at the beginning, when inertia would be dragging it. Is there a way to use bones to accomplish this? But, the handle and briefcase are separate objects, and the bones would deform the briefcase in a weird way if they were the same object right? Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Comment: If you chooose bones .... Bones can work as a hinge to swing rigid meshes.  Use only one bone for handle and one bone for case.  2 bones initially. The weight painiting can isolate influence.  Parent to single bone option may eliminate the need for any weight painting.

Comment: Lots of approaches you could take, but I would avoid using physics for this at all in favor of manual keyframing, provided that you have a very clear scene in mind, with a very regular motion required. Which is likely the case if the briefcase is to be carried in, say, a walk cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am knew to working with bones. So should I make the case and handle one object, or parent the case to the handle when working with bones in this case? Like Ctrl J to join them so it is one briefcase object, then make 2 bones, one for the handle, one for the case, then weight paint the case bone to only deform the case? @atomicbezierslinger

Comment: Two bones as stated above.  One for the handle and one for the case.  The case and handle are two separate meshes. Please show your work with more effort to explanation.  Your image IMHO has value close to zero, since I do have some generic concept of a brief case.  Please show your rotation mechanism in your screen capture.  Try to wiggle the handle a small amount out of the logical mathematical plane if you use rigid body.  Probably your character hand has bones.